# Cisco ASA 5505 изменить порт подключения ASDM

Tags: firewall, cisco

У нас стоит Cisco ASA 5510, стало необходимо опубликовать 443 порт наружу. ASDM начал ругаться о том, что не может зарезервировать этот порт. Как я смог выяснить, это связано с тем, что сам ASDM подключается по 443 порту.

Возможно ли изменить порт подключения ASDM к асе, что бы появилась возможность добавить правило по этому порту?

Версия ASDM 6.3(1), версия прошивки ASA 8.3(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы изменить порт подключения в ASDM требуется зайти в

Configuration -> Device Management -> Management Access -> ASDM/HTTPS/Telnet/SSH

Там в Port Number ввести свой порт. После этого при подключении к ASDM требуется вводить IP адрес асы и порт через двоеточие (например 10.10.10.10:8080).

Так же может потребоваться переключить SSL VPN на другой порт, либо выключить его, т.к. он так же занимает 443 порт.

Поменять порт или отключить SSL VPN можно в Configuration -> Remote Access VPN -> Clientless SSL VPN Access -> Connection Profiles.